# Word BuiltInDocumentProperties don't change

Tags: vba, word-2003

I have a macro in Word 2003 that applies the property fields of the open document to all the .doc's in the same folder. The code works once. If I create a folder, create three new documents in that folder, open of the documents and run the macro, it would work. If I open a document in that folder and run the macro again, it would only change the properties of the active document that ran the macro.

The macro is located in a module of the Normal template.

The code:

```
title = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title")
subject = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Subject")
author = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Author")
manager = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Manager")
company = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Company")
category = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Category")
keywords = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords")
comments = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Comments")

fileDirectory = ActiveDocument.Path

vFile = Dir(fileDirectory & "\*.doc")

Do While vFile <> ""
    Set wordDoc = Documents.Open(fileDirectory & "\" & vFile)
    With wordDoc
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title") = title
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Subject") = subject
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Author") = author
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Manager") = manager
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Company") = company
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Category") = category
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Keywords") = keywords
        .BuiltInDocumentProperties("Comments") = comments
        .Save
        .Close
    End With
    vFile = Dir
Loop
```

I'm not sure if it has something with the way I'm opening or saving the files. At least if it didn't work at all I would know the code is just wrong, but since it works on a new document at least once... I have no idea.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing unusual in that code of the way you run it. Is there anything before first line you presented?

Comment: Just the variable declarations and calling the properties window.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alright, I have it working now. Word has a `.Saved` boolean which apparently if it is set to true already it won't save the changes when you use `.Save` and changing the properties through VBA doesn't seem to count as a important enough change to set the `.Saved` to false. Maybe `.SaveAs` would still work though. Anyways, I added `.Saved = False` before the `.Save` and now it is working just fine.

Just wanted to let anyone know who might ponder the same thing at some point. This might just be a decent way to make sure that the file always saves.

Comment: Yeah, that's a 'Good to Know!'. Or maybe a 'Gotcha!' - I just verified this behaviour in MS-Excel 2010. Excel VBA developers need to apply ThisWorkbook.Saved = False when changing Built-In document properties AND custom document properties.