# VBA word edit title defaut

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to changing the Default File Name "Document 1", in Office 2010

[image: Picture buton clic]

i try this so not working :(

```
Private Sub Document_New()
    Launcher.AutoExec
End Sub
```

---

in the function Launcher.AutoExec :

```
 Set doc = ActiveDocument

    sTitle = "Test 2017"
  doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value = sTitle
```

But i click in file and save as and the name has change :o

---

**SOLUTION** :
if you edit the Normal.dotm so open this file not double click On the File tab,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013,_2010

[image: Picture buton clic]

Edit the title in normal.dotm and future open documents will have the title

Comment: It's helpful for the site if you place all the "solution" information in your own reply then mark that reply as "the answer". (I see you don't have a lot of reputation, yet, but at some point you should be able to mark your reply as the answer to your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION** :
if you edit the Normal.dotm so open this file not double click On the File tab,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea#ID0EAABAAA=2016,_2013,_2010

https://cdn.ablebits.com/_img-blog/excel-document-properties/display-properties-pane.png

Edit the title in normal.dotm and future open documents will have the title

Answer (score 0):

The other way around would work better ;)

```
Set doc = ActiveDocument
    sTitle = "Test 2017"
    doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title").Value = sTitle
    doc.Saved = False
    doc.save
```

Comment: Ah yes my bad so i have same problem i click save and the name is same.
But i click in file and save as and the name has change :o

Comment: @Royalxm : I've added something as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932902/word-builtindocumentproperties-dont-change and if it's still not enough, I hope you find something in there http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/word-powerpoint-outlook-and-other-office-products/306387-changing-word-document-title-via-builtindocumentproperties.html

Comment: i found the solution. my code is in Normal.dotm, so i edit the propriety title this file and so now the name defauts is work's damn lol

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea

Comment: @Royalxm : I'd suggest that you post you answer and accept it so that other can find the solution more easily! ;)